# Unable To Start Opera Mini With The Given URL

Tags: blackberry, opera, applicationmanager

I am using the following code to start the Opera Mini web browser with the given URL;

```java
try {
    ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("operette$2dhifi?" + url);
} catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
    updateInfo(e.toString());
}
```

But its throwing

> ApplicationManagerException: module not found.

When I try without the URL

```java
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("operette$2dhifi");
```

, Opera starts fine. But I don't want to start the blank browser, I want to start it with my URL.

Looked at the BlackBerry forum and googled it also but unable to find the solution. Please guide me in the right direction.

I am developing on

- BlackBerry Eclipse JDE 1.5.0
- BlackBerry Bold 9900

Comment: Can you give us an example of which URL you have tried?  For example, the URL `http://www.google.com` is pretty simple.  If your URL is more complicated, that might be causing problems.  Have you ruled that out?

Comment: @Nate: Thanks for the edit. I've tried the simple URLs.